# How to detect collisions between Sprite and Rect in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been playing around with the GitHub Noops Challenges (https://noopschallenge.com/challenges)
and I got hooked by the mazebot challenge, I created a small game using python and PyGame module where I generate the grid by the JSON string I am provided with from the request (https://api.noopschallenge.com/mazebot/random?minSize=10&maxSize=10).

```py
while(True):
        if(x_pos == 400):
            x_pos = 0
            y_pos += hight
            c += 1
            r = 0
        if(y_pos == 400):
            break

        # draws squares based on the JSON string
        if(rowList[c][r] == ' '):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, White, (x_pos, y_pos, width, hight))

        #need to collide with these
        if(rowList[c][r] == 'X'):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, Black, (x_pos, y_pos, width, hight))

        if(rowList[c][r] == 'A'):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, Pink, (x_pos, y_pos, width, hight))
            if hasDrawn == False:
                CharacterSprite = pygame.image.load('playerSprite.png')
                CharacterSprite_x = x_pos
                CharacterSprite_y = y_pos
                perma_x = x_pos
                perma_y = y_pos
                screen.blit(CharacterSprite, (CharacterSprite_x, CharacterSprite_y))
                hasDrawn = True

        if(rowList[c][r] == 'B'):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, Green, (x_pos, y_pos, width, hight))
            endPos = [x_pos, y_pos]


        x_pos += hight
        r += 1
        i += 1
```

This is the grid drawing code ^ , it loops through the screen adding a colored box based on whether the JSON grid is " "(empty), "X"(wall), "A"(start point) or "B"(end point)
The problem is that I now need the character to be able to collide with the BLACK squares

The whole game board is randomly generated on each launch if it helps. 
The rectangles as shown in the code are not sprites and the character is just a moving image and is not a class

I am quite new to PyGame so sorry if I missed out something important

Image of the game UI:
[image]

Things I've tried:

- I tried 'remembering' in a list where the rectangles were drawn and blocking movement if the character tried to move to the x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates but that hasn't worked
- From what I have looked up, there is no way to 'sense' the color that the character is touching like you could do in scratch to block the movement that way

Comment: instead variables `x1, y1, x2, y2` use object `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size. It has function `rect.colliderect(other_rect)` . You can use Rect also to show image `blit(image, rect)`

Comment: documentation [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: in pygame you keep positions of all object as list with `Rect()` and then you can use `for-loop` to check `rect.colliderect(other_rect)` or you can use `rect.coolidelist(list_of_other_rects)`. If you keep objects in `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` then you can group them with `pygame.sprite.Group` and draw all object with one line - `group.draw()` and check collision between sprite and group - ie. `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, list_of_blocks)`

Comment: documentation [pygame.sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)

Comment: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a geometrically collision test at all. Just verify if there is a 'X' in `rowList` at the positions of the character. If the player is moving smoothly through the mace, then each corner of the charactercan be in a different section of the maze. So you've to do 4 checks.

The size of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) can be get by [`.get_size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size):

```py
cw, ch = CharacterSprite.get_size()
```

The indices of the rows and columns can be calculated by an integral division. In the following `cx` and `cy` are the position of the character:

```py
corners = [(cx, cy), (cx+cw, cy), (cx+cw, cy+ch), (cx, cy+ch)]
corners_i = [(c[0] // width, c[1] // height) for c in corners]
```

Use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to verify if any element in `rowList` is an `X`

```py
is_colliding = any([cr for cr in corners_i if rowList[cr[0]][cr[1]] == 'X'])
```

Store the position of the character before you move. Do the collision test and reset the position of the character if a collision was found:

```py
cur_cx, cur_cy = cx, cy
cw, ch = CharacterSprite.get_size()

# move the character and change cx/cy
# [...]

corners = [(cx, cy), (cx+cw, cy), (cx+cw, cy+ch), (cx, cy+ch)]
corners_i = [(c[0] // width, c[1] // height) for c in corners]
if any([cr for cr in corners_i if rowList[cr[0]][cr[1]] == 'X']):
    cx, cy = cur_cx, cur_cy
```